# How do I correct the undefined method error of a form.for component in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html

I'm doing an application on rails, but when I try to add a component, any, to a form in devise form.for I get the following error:

NoMethodError in Devise::Sessions#new
Showing C:/Users/Carlos/Desktop/pagina web proyecto/web_ruby/app/views/devise/sessions/new.html.erb where line #58 raised:

```
undefined method `materia' for #<Student:0xbccc460>
Extracted source (around line #58):
56      <hr id="separador3Mon">
57      
58      <%= f.text_field :materia%>
59
60      <div class="actions">
61            <%= f.submit "Log in" %>

Rails.root: C:/Users/Carlos/Desktop/pagina web proyecto/web_ruby
```

The code of the lecture is as follows:

```
<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: session_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
     <hr id="separador3Mon">
     <%= f.email_field :codigo, autofocus: true, placeholder: "Codigo" %>
     <hr id="separador3Mon">
     <%= f.password_field :password, placeholder: "Contraseña" %>

     <hr id="separador3Mon">

     <%= f.text_field :materia%>

     <div class="actions">
          <%= f.submit "Log in" %>
     </div>
     <hr id="separador3Mon">
<% end %>
```

I was also pressed in another form but not in devise, with a radio button, I gave up and eliminated them. It does not matter if I change the name of the object or component.

The Student's model:

```
class StudentsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :configure_devise_params, if: :devise_controller?

  def configure_devise_params
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up) do |user|
      user.permit(:codigo, :documento, :nombres, :apellidos, :es_egresado, :email, :password)
    end
  end
  layout 'application'
  #GET /estudiante
  def index
    #TRAER TODOS LOS REGISTROS DE LA TABLA Student
    Student.all
    #PASAR DATOS A LA VISTA - OBTIENE TODOS LOS REGISTROS
    @students = Student.all
  end
  #GET /estudiante/:id
  def show 
    #ENCONTRAR REGISTRO POR EL ID
    @student = Student.find(params[:id])
  end
  #GET /estudiante/ver
  def ver
    @students = Student.all
  end
  #GET /students/new
  def new
    @student = Student.new
  end
  #/POST /students
  def create
    @student = Student.new(
                codigo: params[:student][:codigo],
                documento: params[:student][:documento], 
                            nombres: params[:student][:nombres], 
                            apellidos: params[:student][:apellidos], 
                            es_egresado: params[:student][:es_egresado],
                email: params[:student][:email],
                            encrypted_password: params[:student][:password], 
                            promedio_carrera: 0.0)
    #@student = Student.new(params[student_params])
    if @student.save
        redirect_to @student
    else
        render :new
    end
  end
  #DELETE /students/:id
  def destroy
    @student =  Student.find(params[:id]) #
    @student.destroy #Destroy elimina el objeto de la base de datos
    redirect_to students_path
  end
  #PUT /students/:id
  def update

  end

  private

  def student_params
    params.require(:student).permit(:documento, :nombres, :apellidos, :es_egresado, :clave)
  end

end
```

The model's Student

```
class Student < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable, :trackable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable
  has_many :groups
  has_many :notes

  #RELACION MUCHOS A MUCHOS
  has_and_belongs_to_many :semesters
end
```

And finally, the migration db of Student

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

class DeviseCreateStudents < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :students, {
      :id => false,
      :primary_key => :codigo
    } do |t|
      ## Database authenticatable
      t.integer :codigo, null: false
      t.integer :documento, null: false
      t.string :nombres, null: false
      t.string :apellidos, null: false
      t.integer :es_egresado, null: false

      t.string :email,              null: false, default: ""
      t.string :encrypted_password, null: false, default: ""

      t.decimal :promedio_carrera, null: true

      ## Recoverable
      t.string   :reset_password_token
      t.datetime :reset_password_sent_at

      ## Rememberable
      t.datetime :remember_created_at

      ## Trackable
      # t.integer  :sign_in_count, default: 0, null: false
      # t.datetime :current_sign_in_at
      # t.datetime :last_sign_in_at
      # t.string   :current_sign_in_ip
      # t.string   :last_sign_in_ip

      ## Confirmable
      # t.string   :confirmation_token
      # t.datetime :confirmed_at
      # t.datetime :confirmation_sent_at
      # t.string   :unconfirmed_email # Only if using reconfirmable

      ## Lockable
      # t.integer  :failed_attempts, default: 0, null: false # Only if lock strategy is :failed_attempts
      # t.string   :unlock_token # Only if unlock strategy is :email or :both
      # t.datetime :locked_at


      t.timestamps null: false
    end

    add_index :students, :email,                unique: true
    add_index :students, :reset_password_token, unique: true
    add_index :students, :documento, unique: true
    # add_index :students, :confirmation_token,   unique: true
    # add_index :students, :unlock_token,         unique: true
  end
end
```

Thanks.

Comment: Can you also paste your controller, your Student  model, and your student migration ? At first glance it looks like you're simply missing materia as an attribute on your student model

Comment: @BillyKimble Ok bro, the model, controller and mogration db of student habe been added in the principal post.

Comment: did you make sure to migrate your DB and restart your server?

Comment: @Josh yes, many times I have migrated, rebooted, I have even deleted the entire database don db: drop, but it does not work. I tried it on another pc with another version of ruby different and it does not work either.

Comment: I don't see `materia` in your migration file.  Did you remove it?  You can check from the console by pulling up a `Student` and looking at their attributes.  Also have a look at your `schema.rb` file it should be listed in there.

Comment: Solved bro, did not know that the attribute should be in the migration file and then in the database already installed.
Now I have another more serious error, but to take that into account. Thanks bro.